# DriveApp.makeCopy is not generating a true statement to isGoogleType()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to make a copy of a Google Doc that would then be filled with information from a spreadsheet.  However, I am having issues with the .makeCopy not generating a true value for .isGoogleType().  At least, this appears to be the issue to why I can not access the .getBody of the document.

I've tried testing on a Google Doc that was not created with this script and it seems fine.

```
var templateID = [google doc template ID];
var folderID = [google drive folder ID];

var userDocTitle = "test" + data[i][0];

var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(userDocTitle,DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID));

var blob = copy.getBlob().isGoogleType();
var docid = copy.getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
var body = doc.getBody();
```

I am expecting a .makeCopy of a Google Doc to make a Google Doc file I can access the body.

---

2/15/2019:
Resolved by removing the Insert Drawing from Drive image, or by unlinking it.

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't notice that the Document included Drawing images. I'm sorry. In my environment, I avoid the issue related to the file open by removing the links of Drawing images. Also in your situation, how about removing the link of Drawing image and try again? In the current stage, unfortunately, there are no methods for removing the link in Class DocumentApp and Docs API yet. So it is required to manually remove the links. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. About OP's script:

I think that Google Document copied by `makeCopy()` using OP's script can be used, and the values can be retrieved from the copied Document. If the error occurs yet, can you confirm the mimeType of `templateID` using the following script? I think that it will help users think of about your issue.

```
var mimeType = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).getMimeType();
Logger.log(mimeType)
```

#### 2. About `isGoogleType()`:

Although I'm not sure the date that `isGoogleType()` was added, when Google Docs are retrieved by `getBlob()`, the mimeType automatically becomes `application/pdf`. This can be confirmed by `blob.getContentType()`. I think that this is the reason that `blob.isGoogleType()` is always `false`. But this method is in Class Blob.

From these situations, I thought that `isGoogleType()` might not be able to be directly used for confirming whether the file is Google Docs. So I use a workaround that it retrieves mimeType from file ID. (I think that there are several workarounds for confirming whether the file is Google Docs.) Sample script is as follows.

```
var res = ~DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getMimeType().indexOf("application/vnd.google-apps") ? true : false
```

I use this script instead of `isGoogleType()`. When the file of the file ID is [the files of Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types), `true` is returned. If you want to return `true` only when the file is Spreadsheet, Document and Slides, you can use the following script.

```
String.prototype.isGoogleType2 = function() {
  switch(this.toString()) {
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet":
      return true;
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.document":
      return true;
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation":
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var res = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getMimeType().isGoogleType2();
```

#### References:

- [isGoogleType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#isGoogleType())
- [getContentType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getcontenttype)
- [getMimeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getmimetype)
- [Supported MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and ran into similar issues with `isGoogleType()`. It seems that it wont return true even if the blob is definitely a document (just copied or not).

However, the rest of the script should stll function fine and return the Body. See my example below.

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docBlob = doc.getBlob();
  Logger.log(docBlob.isGoogleType()); //false

  var fileCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).makeCopy("TMP: Delete Me");
  var fileBlob = fileCopy.getBlob();
  Logger.log(fileBlob.isGoogleType()); //false

  var docCopy = DocumentApp.openById(fileCopy.getId());
  Logger.log(docCopy.getBody().getText()); //still a valid Document with a body that return a value.
```

If this doesn't completely answer your question we would need to see the errors you are getting when trying to get the Body of your `doc` object variable.

Comment: That's interesting about the isGoogleType() being false.  My error then is "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 23, file "Code")" on the var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid); line.

Comment: @TedTurner It seems like your main issue isn't the type verification but with getting the body of the copy? Could you, within the same script, try to copy a different Google Document and do the same function as a test?

Comment: Yes, if I use an ID of a Google Doc I made manually, I can get the body.  If I use an ID generated from "DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy(userDocTitle,DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID))" even manually entering the ID, I can not get the Document Body.

I tried something else just now and am not sure what is occuring.  If I open my "template" Google Doc manually, make copy, then use that ID, I can not get the Document Body either.  So many I don't understand what getBody is doing fully?  My goal is to search and replace text in a Document that has a mix of text and tables.

Comment: I found the source of the problem, but am not sure how to fix it.  In this Google Doc, I used a newer feature to Insert Drawing from Drive.  If I remove this drawing, I can open the body of the document.  If I add the drawing back, I can not open the body of the document.  So it seems to be a limitation around the Insert Drawing from Drive.

Comment: That's really interesting. Consider submitting a bug report to the Apps Script team!